# have_tag vs. have_selector

Tags: rspec, selector

I've been using have_selector with RSpec (version 2.0.1) successfully.  I recently found documentation on have_tag ... with_tag ... associated with RSpec 1.3.2 and would like to use it, but RSpec gives me the error:

```
undefined method `has_tag?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x105584e80>
```

on the following lines:

```
      response.should have_tag("div.breadcrumbs select") do
        with_tag(:option, :value => @brands.name)
        with_tag(:option, :value => @marketsize.name)
      end
```

I've tried the same syntax substituting "have_selector" and "with_selector for "have_tag" and "with_tag", in which case I get the error message

```
undefined method `with_selector' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x105379de8>
```

I've also tried leaving the "with_tag" alone while substituting "have_selector" with no success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Took me a while to find it in the documentation, but the correct answer is

```
  response.should have_selector("div.breadcrumbs select") do |content|
    content.should have_selector(:option, :value => @brands.name)
    content.should have_selector(:option, :value => @marketsize.name)
  end
```

Comment: You could provide here the link to the documentation you found.

Comment: Great find, +1 from me, although I used  content.should have_selector('dl')

Comment: I don't think this works. The block is apparently ignored... I'm afraid you are not really asserting anything about the content here.

Comment: what I'd like to know is how can I make sure brands.name precede marketsize.name ?

Comment: @AlexChaffee is right. This will pass every time, but it is a false positive. The block is ignored (though why baffles me)

Answer (score 5):

> RSpec-2 will not include have_tag. Use webrat's have_selector matcher instead.

http://groups.google.com/group/rspec/browse_thread/thread/1c254524d6859ba9