# Rspec 3.X: native built in html matchers? Or do we have to use Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, rspec3

I've been reading a ton of docs and SO questions/ answers on all the changes as Rspec has evolved, want to be sure of the answer...

My goal is to **use native Rspec-rails (I have 3.2.2) to do integrated controller/view tests that look for 1) CSS classes and 2) ID selectors.** In other words given this view snippet:

```
<!-- staticpages/dashboard -->
<div class="hidden">Something</div>
<div id="creation">This</div>
```

This should pass (however it should be semantically written):

```
describe StaticpagesController do
  render_views

  it "should find everything" do
    get :dashboard
    expect(response.body).to have_selector("div#creation")
    expect(response.body).to have_css("hidden")
    expect(response.body).to_not have_selector("div#nothinghere")
  end
end
```

**I would like to do this without additional gems like Capybara; is that possible?**

Here's a high level of what I've learned so far:

- in Rspec 1, the `have_tag` feature allowed you to do this (http://glenngillen.com/thoughts/using-rspec-have-tag)
- in Rspec 2, the `have_tag` was replaced with webrat's `have_selector` ([have_tag vs. have_selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362493/have-tag-vs-have-selector))
- in Rspec 3, webrat support has been removed (http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/)

In my own experimentation, the code above generated:

```
Expect<long response.body here>.to respond to `has_selector?`
```

So that has indeed been deprecated. Still, I'd love to know if there's some other way to do this that I don't know about.

**IF it turns out I need Capybara to do these fancy matchers**, is there a way to do this in my integrated controller/view specs? My understanding is that I have to add `type: :feature` to the `describe StaticpagesController` line to use Capybara's matchers. However, the minute I do that, `render_views` is no longer available (since it's limited to `type: :controller`). Note, `render_views` also dies if, per this post (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-99/docs/controller-specs/use-of-capybara-in-controller-specs), I manually `include Capybara::DSL` into my controller spec. Anyway, I would really like to not have to rewrite my current controller specs into a bunch of feature specs...

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you want feature specs (with Capybara) more than controller specs as [you're not testing any of the things controller specs are typically used to test](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/controller-specs) such as:

- whether a template is rendered
- whether a redirect occurs
- what instance variables are assigned in the controller to be shared with the view
- the cookies sent back with the response

Also, you probably want to consider writing feature specs for new apps over controller specs since [controller tests will probably be dropped in Rails 5](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950#issuecomment-77924771) in favor of the writing of integration/feature tests.

For a description of the different kinds of specs that you could write, and what they're typically used for, 
see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17010855/567863).

Comment: So honestly, I just included the part of the test that was more "feature" in my code snippet above. I have extensive controller testing that is testing for proper redirects, templates, instance variables, etc... but I guess if there's no other way...

Comment: Don't think so. Even [the RSpec documentation on feature specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec) says that if you're testing a use case through your  external-facing interface, in this case web pages, then it should be under a feature spec.  If for whatever reason you're not a fan of feature tests, then I guess a [view spec](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/view-specs) may be what you're after if you just want to test rendering a view...?  Regardless, like the feature spec, it would have to be in a separate file anyway.